# look and feel of app in launch image and launch screen

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, launch-screen, launchimage

I created an app in xamarin ios and used launch image option to show the launch screen. Now I replaced the launch image with launch screen (.xib file). But after changing to launch screen from launch image the look and feel of my app is also affected. Now the fonts are looking small and controls on screens are also looking little small. The size of fonts and other controls are same in both cases but looking different in both launch image case and launch screen case.

I really don't know what is the problem in it, why app looks different in both cases.

Does anyone have any idea why does it happen?

Comment: Does tis happen on specific devices? It might be possible that native resolutions are only available when an app uses the launch xibs. Especially on an 10.5" iPad the difference might be very subtle.

Comment: it is happening in all iphone devices, if I install an app with launch image it looks different and if I install same app with launch screen it looks different

Comment: Did you populate image with all the type in LaunchImages?

Comment: Yes, except Iphone X, because I don't have the option to add it in xamarin ios